# Get last 5 rows but in order created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has the following information:

mesID is my identity seed

```
mesID | ToUser | FromUser | DateTime
-------------------------------------
91    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:10:23 PM
92    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:20:38 PM
93    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:35:14 PM
94    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:20:38 PM
95    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:35:14 PM
98    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:10:23 PM
101   | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:20:38 PM
104   | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:35:14 PM
109   | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:54:11 PM
```

now keep in mind i have over 60 more messages that are lower mesID then 98. What I want to do is get only the last 5 messages, but keep them in the original order from oldest to newest message returned (mesID = 1 obviously would be the oldest).

logically I would think I would just get the top 5 returns and order it by mesID by DESC. Then after the 5 have been returned then re-order them by mesID AESC, but I have no clue how to do this.

So the end result i would get something like...

```
95    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:35:14 PM
98    | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:10:23 PM
101   | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:20:38 PM
104   | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:35:14 PM
109   | jason  | krissy   | 1/18/2013 12:54:11 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perform a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  mesid IN (SELECT TOP 5 mesid
                 FROM   TABLE
                 WHERE ToUser like '%krissy%' or FromUser like '%krissy%'  
                 ORDER BY
                        mesid DESC)
ORDER BY
       mesid ASC
```

Comment: i guess i shoulda put my full question because I thought the following would work..

Comment: @eqiz like that above? you did say OR (not AND?)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT TOP 5 *
           FROM   TABLE
           ORDER BY
                  mesID DESC
       ) t
ORDER BY
       t.mesID
```

Comment: brykneval this only displays the top 5 unfortunately ordered the opposite way.

Comment: This is the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

This will get latest 5, *assuming there are many records with toUSer and FromUser*, for every user.

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT mesID, ToUSer, FromUser, DateTime,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ToUSer, FromUser
                                ORDER BY mesID DESC) rn
    FROM tableName
)
SELECT mesID, ToUSer, FromUser, DateTime
FROM recordList
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY mesID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fcf5/2)

Comment: this works, but I needed it in a standard sql method without using "with" but I still gave you a plus +1 thanks for feedback in showing a different method

Comment: @eqiz ok, i'm using `CTE` because it is supported in `SQL Server` as you tagged it along with your question `:D`

Comment: this is just too complex for the task

Comment: @Bulat yes, because I was overthinking. The above query works if you want to get **Top 5 rows for each group of `ToUser` and `FromUser`**. I'm pretty sure the table is not only for *jason and krissy*, there's more than them.